# finding prime factors code doesn't work, why not?

Tags: python

i am new to coding and learning so please excuse any amateur questions/code.

I have an assignment to write code where you can enter a number and it returns prime factors. I have written something but it doesn't work and i cannot figure out why. Hoping someone can help, mind you, there is probably a billion ways to do it better but i would like to know why mine doesn't work and how to fix mine.

```
def all_factors():
    '''first create a list of all factors'''
    number = int(input("please enter a number: ")) # ask for number
    prime_list = [] # this is gonna be the prime factor list
    check_list= list(range(2,number)) # all the numbers up to the input number. 
    factor_list = [] #all the factors of the inputnumber, including non-primes
    for factor in check_list:
        if number%factor == 0:
            factor_list.append(factor)
    
    
    ''' function to check if factor is a prime number'''

    
    prime_list = factor_list.copy()
    
    for num in prime_list: 
                
        if num%2 == 0 and num!= 2: '''remove even numbers except 2'''
            prime_list.remove(num)
            
            
        elif num%2!=0 and num!= 2:  '''remove odd numbers that are not prime '''
            try_list = list(range(2,num))
            for check in try_list:
                if num%check == 0:
                    prime_list.remove(num)
                    pass
                
    result = set(prime_list)
    print(result)
    print('the factor list is ',factor_list)
    print('the prime list is ',prime_list)
```

However, i ran it with two examples, number 60 and number 120 and it didn't work. 60 give me a list with still even numbers in it. And 120 gave an error. How come the number 10 for example is not removed off the prime list?

```
please enter a number: 60
{2, 3, 5, 10, 15, 30}
the factor list is  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30]
the prime list is  [2, 3, 5, 10, 15, 30]
```

and output using 120:

```
please enter a number: 120
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-fc97ce9d24c1> in <module>
----> 1 all_factors()

<ipython-input-16-bb4c2a026f3b> in all_factors()
     25             for check in try_list:
     26                 if num%check == 0:
---> 27                     prime_list.remove(num)
     28                     pass
     29 

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason is that you suppress elements from the list you are iterating.
Replace `for num in prime_list:`  by `for num in factor_list:`  and, as said **go2nivana**, check existence before to remove.

Comment: Thank you! This and the solution of g02nivano worked! (terribly sorry for late answer). Apparently python does not like when you change the list you iterate through. Good thing to know.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove an element that is not present in `prime_list`. To avoid that you should preform a check first:

```
if num in prime_list:
    prime_list.remove(num)
```

Comment: Thank you! This and the solution of Captain Flam worked! (terribly sorry for late answer)